# How to check if a pre-compiled libtcmalloc.so is compiled without libunwind?

Tags: tcmalloc, gperftools, libunwind

I do not know where to even start, apologies for the noob question but seems there's nothing on this specific case in SO unless there's more generic terms I do not know.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Bad bot. Literally in the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recent (like 5+ years or so), gperftools support environment variable that dumps used backtracing method. Set TCMALLOC_STACKTRACE_METHOD_VERBOSE to 1 and it'll show what it uses by default. You can also override used method via TCMALLOC_STACKTRACE_METHOD environment variable.

Another option is via package manager. On my debian system I see that libtcmalloc-minimal4 is linked without libunwind (as expected since it doesn't capture any backtraces), and libgoogle-perftool4 does depend in libunwind8. On debian and ubuntu you can see that by running apt-cache show .